# React get codemirror value onClick

Tags: reactjs, codemirror, react-codemirror

I am trying to get the following code below to display the CodeMirror onChange value when the button is clicked and then display that value inside the "output" div.

I am fairly new to react so not sure if it's best to pass the value through state or if there's an easier method.

Here is my code so far:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { UnControlled as CodeMirror } from "react-codemirror2";
import "codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript";
import "codemirror/lib/codemirror.css";

export default class Code extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <CodeMirror
          value='console.log("Hello World")'
          options={{
            mode: "javascript",
            lineNumbers: true
          }}
          onChange={(editor, data, value) => {
            console.log(value);
          }}
        />
        <button onClick={}>run code</button>

        <div className="Output">
          <p>// Value should go here</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `state` to maintain your values, and show output from your state,

```
class Code extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      runCode: false,
      outputText: 'console.log("Hello World")',
    }
  }
  runCode = () => {
    this.setState({runCode: true})
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <CodeMirror
          value={this.state.outputText}
          options={{
            mode: 'javascript',
            lineNumbers: true,
          }}
          onChange={(editor, data, value) => {
            this.setState({
              runCode: false,
              outputText: value,
            })
          }}
        />
        <button onClick={this.runCode}>run code</button>

        <div className="Output">
          <pre>{this.state.runCode && this.state.outputText}</pre>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-q5bgd?fontsize=14) - Output appended on click of button.

[Demo1](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-qvzhk?fontsize=14) - Outout appended as you type in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a state in such situations:

```
export default class Code extends Component {
    state={
       value: ''
     }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <CodeMirror
          value='console.log("Hello World")'
          options={{
            mode: "javascript",
            lineNumbers: true
          }}
          onChange={(editor, data, value) => {
            this.setState({value});
          }}
        />
        <button onClick={}>run code</button>

        <div className="Output">
          <p>{this.state.value}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```